# Как заполнить атрибут value в цикле значениями переменной цикла, i?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Приветствую всех. Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста, как мне заполнить атрибут value элемента option в цикле с проверяемым условием. Просто если в массиве tema найдено всего одно совпадение, он выводит в браузер один элемент option, но со значением 2 вместо 1.

```
for(var i=0,a=1; i<tema.length; i++,a++) {  
        if(tema[i] != tema[a]){  
        name_test_box += '<option value="' + i + '">' + $('label[for=drink'+tema[i]+']').text() + '</option>';  
        }  
}
```

Comment: вы хотите вывести только уникальные значения массива?

Comment: Да, именно так. Но вопрос не про это. Я только часть кода привел. Если интересно, то массив tema содержит только числовые значения в неупорядоченном виде. Сначала я упорядочиваю этот массив методом sort(), ну а затем работает вышеприведенный цикл.  Мне нужно заполнить все option-ы значениями переменной цикла. Вида, 1,2,3... Но если цикл пропускает первый элемент, в случае если он совпал со вторым, первому option-у присваивается значение атрибута value 2.

Comment: Нашел на одном форуме, один юзер предлагает делать так. Говорит, что читал статью на хабре и этот метод самый быстрый.
var used = {};
var data = [];
for(var i=0,a=0; i<1000000; i++,a++) {
  if(a>2) {a=0;}
  data[i] = {"name_id":1+a, "name_test":"Первый тест"};
}
console.time('test');
var dim = data.filter(function(obj) {
return obj.name_id in used ? 0:(used[obj.name_id]=1);
});
console.timeEnd('test');
Выполняет миллион итераций всего за 133 мс. Этот код возвращает объект только с уникальными значениями. Повторяющиеся пропускает.

Comment: @Dimaz Да, Вы правы, но в IE6  данный метод с массивами/json-объектом не работает (скорее всего и в IE7 тоже), ибо как было замечено ранее **this only works on DOM elements** (метод filter работает только с объектами JQuery DOM).

Предлагаю использовать немного модифицированную функцию. Смотрите в ответ.

И да, если Вы заметили, то я оптимизировал 

    $('label[for=drink' + tema[i] + ']');

и в ответе объяснил, почему Ваш вариант "тяжелее".

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * Функция возвращает массив из элементов с уникальными значениями
 */
function unique(array){
    return $.grep(
        array, 
        function(el, index) {
            return index == $.inArray(el, array);
        }
    );
}

var tema = [1,1,3,2,2,3,6,7,8,2,1,9],
    name_test_box = '',
    arr = [];

tema = unique(tema).sort();

$('label[for^="drink"]', '#form_1').each(
    function() { 
        var str_for = $(this).attr('for');
        if (str_for) {
            arr[str_for] = this.innerHTML;
        }
    }
);

for (var i = 0, count = tema.length; i < count; i++) { 
    if (!arr['drink' + tema[i]]) {
        continue;
    }

    name_test_box += 
    '<option value="' + tema[i] + '">' + 
    arr['drink' + tema[i]] + 
    '</option>';    
}
```

Комметарий:

Используйте по возможности context при поиске элементов DOM, а именно:

```
$('label[for^="drink"]', '#form_1')
```

, где **form_1** - id формы.

т.е. изначально осуществляется поиск контекста, в данном случае формы, в котором будет происходить поиск всех элементов **label** с атрибутом **for**, значение которого начинается со строки **drink**.

Внутри же цикла, мы будем оперировать уже найденным массивом **arr** с необходимыми значениями, а не искать элементы в цикле каждый раз (в каждой итерации) по всему DOM-дереву элементов.

P.S. Валидно и для IE6.

---

**UPD:**

```
function unique(array){
    var used = {},
        isIE = $.browser.msie && $.browser.version <= 8 && !window.XMLHttpRequest;
     return (isIE) 
        ? $.grep(
            array, 
            function(el, index) {
                return index == $.inArray(el, array);
            }
        )

        : array.filter(function(obj) {
            return obj in used ? 0 : (used[obj] = 1);
        });    
}
```

Тестовые данные:

```
var data=[];
/* заполняем массив повторяющимися значениями */
for(var i = 0, a = 0; i < 100000; i++, a++) {
    if (a > 2) {
        a = 0
    }

    data[i] = 1 + a;
}

console.time('time');
console.log(unique(data));
console.timeEnd('time');
```

Comment: Что-то не работает.  
    var data = [1,1,3,2,2,3,6,7,8,2,1,9].sort();  
$.unique(data);  
console.log(data);    
Выводит [3, 9, 8, 7, 6, 3, 2, 1]

Comment: ну вообще-то

>[jQuery.unique()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/)

Description: Sorts an array of DOM elements, in place, with the duplicates removed. Note that this only works on arrays of DOM elements, not strings or numbers.

Comment: Похоже, что разработчики jQuery просчитались. Метод работает не так как нужно.))

Comment: Все ясно.) Как же тогда быть?

Comment: @Dimaz Воспользуйтесь:

    function unique(array){
        return $.grep(
      array, 
      function(el, index) {
             return index == $.inArray(el, array);
         }
     );
    }

Примечание: Валидно и для IE6.

Тогда:

    tema = unique(tema).sort();

Мне вот этот кусок не нравится:

    $('label[for=drink' + tema[i] + ']');


ККак сделаю, отредактирую ответ

Comment: Спасибо. Завтра попробую.